# Adding output files to an existing output directory in Mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to add output files of a map reduce program to the same directory every time I run the job by appending time stamp at the end of file name.

Currently i am able append the time stamp at the end of file output file, but I am unable to find out how to add files to the same output directory instead of overwriting it every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write output files in temporary folder and move them to target folder after the end of job. Example of a method that moves all files from one folder to another:

```
public static void moveFiles(Path from, Path to, Configuration conf) throws IOException {
    FileSystem fs = from.getFileSystem(conf); // get file system
    for (FileStatus status : fs.listStatus(from)) { // list all files in 'from' folder
        Path file = status.getPath(); // get path to file in 'from' folder
        Path dst = new Path(to, file.getName()); // create new file name
        fs.rename(file, dst); // move file from 'from' folder to 'to' folder
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently I am following the same logic what ever mentioned by you by using Fileutil.copy, but the problem is that it is changing the time stamp for the previously generated files also because of copying, I want to preserve the time stamp for the previously generated files.

Comment: As i understand you just copy the new files to the target folder. Why is it changes time stamps for previously generated files?

Comment: Fileutil.copy will move the files from source to destination because of which timestamp is getting changed. Now I have changed it to fs.rename. It is not changing timestamp. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The output can be controlled by using reduce method. I guess you can try out a logic in reducer.

Please note that number of reducers = number of output files.